# MySQL full outer join help please

Tags: mysql

I know MySQL full outer join is syntax error.
I have a full outer join in mysql5 would like to create a similar query.
What do I do?

Comment: Use a UNION of a LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately, your first attempt at asking a question is decidedly flawed. Suggest read the guidelines and amend/start again.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can emulate FULL OUTER JOIN using UNION (from MySQL 4.0.0 on):

with two tables t1, t2:

SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id

with three tables t1, t2, t3:

SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
```